# Is the GoShogun OP being translated correctly?

Tags: japanese-language, theme-song, goshogun

Out of a mix of nostalgia and curiosity (since I watched *Macron 1* as a kid), I started watching the ye olde *GoShogun* anime on Amazon, which I *think* uses Discotek's localization. The subtitles for the first two lyrics of the opening song (after the "5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0" countdown) seem odd though:

> Do you know the red button?
> Do you know the blue button?

Is that really what the song says?

FWIW, here's the Romaji of those lyrics according to https://www.virtual-rotation.com/chirlind/others/sentai/goshou.html:

> Akai botan wo shitteru ka?
> Aoi botan wo shitteru ka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, the English translation is correct.**

For comparison, here is the lyric in Japanese:

> (5!　4!　3!　2!　1!　0!)
>
> 赤いボタンを　知ってるか
> 青いボタンを　知ってるか
> [...]

<sup>Lyrics taken from [Uta-Net+](https://www.uta-net.com/movie/14189/eDbcoNkj3Jc/) (Japanese)</sup>

Which does translate to

> (5! 4! 3! 3! 2! 1! 0!)
>
> Do you know the red button?
> Do you know the blue button?
> [...]